# Server has "weak cipher setting" according to security audit, replaced offending cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, but still failing retest audit?

Tags: security, ssl, cipher

We received an audit from our local cyber security team in which one of our servers displays "Insufficient Transport Layer Protection".

According to their description:

"
DESCRIPTION: 
The server supports the following weak ciphers:

- TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA [0x0a] RSA 3DES 168

  These ciphers are known to have cryptographic weaknesses that make them unsuitable for use in SSL/TLS.
  "

The solution they've provided are as follows:

"
SOLUTION: We recommend disabling support for the export and null cipher suites, as well as cipher suites using RC4/3DES. Instead, we suggest AES128-SHA for TLS 1.0 and 1.1, and AES128-GCM-SHA256 for TLS 1.2. 
"

**In an attempt to rectify this, this is what I have done so far:**

1. Run -> gpedit.msc -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> SSL Configuration Settings
2. Clicked on SSL Cipher Suite Order
3. Clicked on radio button "Enabled"
4. Replaced the string of supported cipher suites with this one:

   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_CK_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5
5. Rebooted server and ran retest using nmap utility application.

We ran a retest on our server, and it appears the vulnerability is still outgoing:

[Image of nmap result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf600.png)

Our box is a Windows 2008 R2 server.

Is there another method on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new cipher suite string you installed still has 3DES ciphers in it.  Get rid of anything in the list with the word DES.

Comment: Awesome, a second pair of eyes always seems to help. I should have double checked the list of cipher suites that was given to us, thank you for pointing this out to me. Cheers